# apache royale command line Error: unknown configuration variable js-dynamic-access-unknown-members

Tags: apache-royale

I am trying to build tour de jewel sample project,
downloaded from: [nightly build number #1861](http://apacheroyaleci2.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com:8080/job/royale-asjs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/out/)

I'am using Visual Studio Code.
But can not build with termainal message :

```
Executing task: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe -jar     
c:\Users\Usr\.vscode\extensions\bowlerhatllc.vscode-nextgenas-1.3.0\bin\asconfigc.jar --sdk 
C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@apache-royale\royale-js\royale-asjs --debug=true - 
-project d:\xampp\htdocs\apache-royale-0.9.8-bin-js-1861\royale- 
asjs\examples\jewel\TourDeJewel\asconfig.json <

MXMLJSC
+royalelib=C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@apache-royale\royale-js\royale- 
asjs\frameworks
--debug=true
+configname=royale
--targets=JSRoyale
--source-path+=src/main/resources
--source-map=true
--html-template=src/main/resources/jewel-example-index-template.html
--theme=${royalelib}/themes/JewelTheme/src/main/resources/defaults.css
-js-dynamic-access-unknown-members=true
--
src/main/royale/App.mxml
command line Error: unknown configuration variable 'js-dynamic-access-unknown-members'.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded and tested that concrete version and seems to be working fine. Even release version too:

```
> Executing task in folder TourDeJewel: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar /Users/carlosrovira/.vscode/extensions/bowlerhatllc.vscode-nextgenas-1.3.0/bin/asconfigc.jar --sdk /Users/carlosrovira/Dev/Royale/Sdks/apache-royale-0.9.8-bin-js/royale-asjs --debug=true --project /Users/carlosrovira/Dev/Royale/Source/royale-asjs/examples/jewel/TourDeJewel/asconfig.json <

MXMLJSC
+royalelib=/Users/carlosrovira/Dev/Royale/Sdks/apache-royale-0.9.8-bin-js/royale-asjs/frameworks
--debug=true
+configname=royale
--targets=JSRoyale
--source-path+=src/main/resources
--source-map=true
--html-template=src/main/resources/jewel-example-index-template.html
--theme=${royalelib}/themes/JewelTheme/src/main/resources/defaults.css
-js-dynamic-access-unknown-members=true
--
src/main/royale/App.mxml
The project 'App' has been successfully compiled.
4.049057994 seconds

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I'm using `CMD+SHIFt+B` and then selecting `Build Debug with AS3 Extension Tour De Jewel` (and `Build Release with AS3 Extension Tour De Jewel`)

Maybe is something in your config. Please check the following links:

- https://apache.github.io/royale-docs/get-started
- https://apache.github.io/royale-docs/get-started/hello-world